# Alternatives to Multiple Listboxes?

Tags: listbox, asp.net-2.0

The current ASP.NET site that I am working on calls for multiple listboxes, 3 to be exact.   The first is for artists, second is for albums, and the last one is for songs. If you select an item from the artist listbox the album listbox will show the albums for that artist and the song listbox will show all the songs from that album im sure you guys can grasp what I am talking about here.

I have it all working, not a problem with that but I find the listbox control to be rather  bland. I was looking at silverlight which would work but its support for only windows wont help any, my only other options that I can think of would be to use flash but I want to avoid that as well.

What I am asking here is, is their another control that I could use to better stylize and custom design to make it fit better with my site while also keeping it simple for the user like the listbox? Before I venture into uncharted waters with flash (dont have experience with this) I wanted to get some input from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you say Silverlight only supports Windows?  It's great on Macs as well!

Comment: From what I have read it seems as if the Moonlight project has only accomplished getting silverlight down to v1. Dont get me wrong thats an incredible progress but I dont want to limit my visitors thats why I dont want to go the flash/silverlight route. I am open for suggestions the way that I see it its either flex/air (forgot which was for web) and silverlight as html can only do so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Drag and drop functionality offered by jquery UI and scriptaculous instead of using multiple listboxes. The downside to this is that it wont work for people with javascript disabled , so you might still need the multiple listboxes as a fall back mechanism.